# How to get and groupby month based on date using java?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, pojo

This is my json data based on the date i want to sort and group by and find total SMSSentId.
The problem is same month have more than sms sent Please help me

data.json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bed54862c2630dd29ecce0"),
    "SMSSentId" : [
        "51b6f5fde4b0dd92df2c3270",
        "51b866e9e4b021170dd1ae1c"
    ],
    "sDate" : 02-Oct 2015,
    "status" : "S"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bed54862c2630dd29ecce0"),
    "SMSSentId" : [
        "51b6f5fde4b0dd92df2c3270"
    ],
    "sDate" : 02-Oct 2015,
    "status" : "S"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bed54862c2630dd29ecce0"),
    "SMSSentId" : [
        "5416e31ae4b0fb949a58942f"
        "51b866e9e4b021170dd1ae1c"
    ],
    "sDate" : 09-Oct 2015,
    "status" : "S"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bed54862c2630dd29ecce0"),
    "SMSSentId" : [
        "51b876d5e4b021170dd1b09c",
        "51b87736e4b021170dd1b09f",
    ],
    "sDate" : 01-Jan 2016,
    "status" : "S"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bed54862c2630dd29ecce0"),
    "SMSSentId" : [
        "51b87736e4b021170dd1b09f",
    ],
    "sDate" : 01-Apr 2016,
    "status" : "S"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57bed54862c2630dd29ecce0"),
    "SMSSentId" : [
        "51b87736e4b021170dd1b09f",
        "51b6f5fde4b0dd92df2c3270"
    ],
    "sDate" : 01-Apr 2016,
    "status" : "S"
}
```

these values are already have SMSLog Pojo class

```
 class SMSLog{

     private String id;
     private List<String>SMSSentId;
     private String sDate;
     private String status;
 }
```

how to process these data

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    List<SmsLog> report;
    for (SmsLog smsLog : report) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception ae) {
            System.out.println(ae.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to expecting this output using core java logic...

```
# | Month |  Year  | TotalSMSSent
1    Oct     2015   5
2    Jan     2016   2
3    Apr     2016   1
```

TotalSMSSent is total count of SMSSentId in each month suppose same month have multiple documents.Thankyou..